# What operator is equivalent to "Is not greater than or equal to"?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view showing a list of events. The events are sorted by a date field, which a user can use to input the event starting date/time. However, I want the events removed from the list once the current time is 1 hour past the start date/time of the event. When I add the event date to the view filters, I get the following operators.

[image]

However, none of these operators give me the desired result. What I really want is a "Is not greater than or equal to" operator. All of this said, is there a workaround that I could easily implement to get my desired result?

Comment: Isn't "is not greater than or equal to" the same as "is less than or equal to"? And why don't you simply say "is less than" now  +1 hour?

Answer (score 1):

You must use "Is less than" with an offset - just like the screenshot.